# VUE application Response data useing Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm developing a VUE application, and I am trying to figure out how to handle post responses in Axios.  I wrote it and used vue-router to make the fetch but decided to try out Axios.

Axious code:

```js
methods: {
        sendForm () {
            console.log("submitHandler called - success!");

            const payload = {
    
                first_name: this.event.firstName,
                last_name: this.event.lastName,
                email: this.event.email,
                password: this.event.password,
                name: this.event.agencyName,
                abbreviation: this.event.abbreviation,
                type: this.event.agencyType,
                address: this.event.agencyAddress,
                city: this.event.agencyCity,
                state: this.event.state,
                zipcode: this.event.zipcode,
                phone: this.event.phone,

            }

            axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL+"/agency/add",payload)
                .then(function (response) {

                    console.log('Response', response)

                            //reformat returned expiration date for displaying on webpage
                            console.log("Expiry date:", response.data.data.agency.expiry);
                            let expd = dayjs(response.data.data.agency.expiry).format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY");

                            //Write retunred values to storeage
                            store.user = {
                                id: response.data.data.user.id,
                                first_name: response.data.data.user.first_name,
                                last_name: response.data.data.user.last_name,
                                email: response.data.data.user.email,
                                agency_name: response.data.data.agency.name,
                                expiry_date: expd,
                            }

                            router.push("/SignUpConfirm");

                })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error', error.message);

                     Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: error.message,
                    })

                })
                 }

        }
```

My issue/question is, for some reason, I have to use "response.data.data.foo" to drill to the response I want.

When I used the built-in view router, I just used "data.foo"

Vue-router option:

```js
methods: {
        submitHandler() {
            console.log("submitHandler called - success!");

            const payload = {
    
                first_name: this.firstName,
                last_name: this.lastName,
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                agency_name: this.agencyName,
                abbreviation: this.abbreviation,
                agency_type: this.agencyType,
                agency_address: this.agencyAddress,
                agency_city: this.agencyCity,
                state: this.state,
                zipcode: this.zipcode,
                phone: this.phone,

            }

            const requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            }

            fetch(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL+"/agency/add", requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.log("Error:", response.message);

                     Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: response.message,
                    })

                } else {
                    //reformat returned expiration date for displaying on webpage
                    console.log("Expiry date:", response.data.agency.expiry);
                    let expd = dayjs(response.data.agency.expiry).format("dddd, MMMM D YYYY");

                    //Write retunred values to storeage
                    store.user = {
                        id: response.data.user.id,
                        first_name: response.data.user.first_name,
                        last_name: response.data.user.last_name,
                        email: response.data.user.email,
                        agency_name: response.data.agency.name,
                        expiry_date: expd,
                    }

                    router.push("/SignUpConfirm");
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API response is probably something like this (after parsing JSON of course)

```
{
    data: {
        user: {
            ......
        }        
    }
}
```

For clarity, lets say it is instead returning

```
{
    topLevel: {
        nextLevel: {
            ......
        }        
    }
}
```

so, below, `toplevel` would actually be `data`, and `nextLevel` would actually be `user` ... but, using these abstract names of toplevel and nextLevel should help illustrate why you end up with `data.data` in axios

axios response schema is as follows

```
{
    data: {}, // server response
    status: 200, // response status
    statusText: 'OK', // response status text
    headers: {}, // response headers
    // etc - there's more but not relevant
}
```

So in

```
axios.post(....)
.then(function (response) {
})
```

then `nextLevel` is clearly `response.data.topLevel.nextlevel`

Note that the response from the server here is a property of the `data` property of the `response` variable - i.e. two "levels" inside the `response` variable

When using fetch

```
fetch(....)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => .....)
```

(it doesn't help clarity that you use `response` in both `.then` by the way, I'd use `result` in the second .then)

in the above, the FIRST `response` is

```
{
    status: 200, // response status
    statusText: 'OK', // response status text
    headers: {}, // response headers
    body: // a readableStream of the response body
    json() {}, // method to parse the body as json
    // .... etc 
}
```

and the second `response` is the parsed JSON response from your server,
so in this case `nextLevel` is `response.topLevel.nextLevel`

And the response from the server here is a property of (the second) `response` variable